# How to remove animation from object?

Tags: raphael

How to remove animation from object in raphael?

```js
var animation  = Raphael.animation({opacity:.2}, 1000);
var circle = paper.circle(0, 0, 5).animate(animation.repeat(Infinity));
```

I want to perform animation on object until some moment in time. And the question is how to remove/stop animation in that specific moment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I really don't know why, but the fiddle works if don't pass any arguments to the stop method. Despite what Raphael's documentation says, I found a working example of an animation stopping  in [this](http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php?v=2#pagetop) site (is not the most beatiful site, by the way, but they have an example for each raphael method!)

Here you have the Fiddle working. http://jsfiddle.net/fKxqS/2/

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop the animation after a specific timelapse...

```
setTimeout(circle.stop(animation), 500) //500 is milliseconds, so it's 0.5s
```

If you want to stop the animation after an event, such as a click

```
circle.click(function(){
  circle.stop(animation)
})
```

**Edit:** Seems Raphael doesn't stop if repeat is set to Infinite, perhaps somebody knows a workaround, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fKxqS/

Comment: Thanks to @limoragni. You have to call Element.stop() instead of Element.stop(animation). But thank you for your answer anyway :)

Comment: Its all about collaboration! Saludos!